# How to copy values from one to another sheet and calculates a result? (VBA Excel)

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following example:

`Sheet1`:

[image]

`Sheet2`:

[image]

`Main`:

[image]

The main sheet needs all values from `Sheet1`. That means, I need the whole columns because it always be adds new IDs. In `Sheet2` are listed the discounts for some articles. So, the target is, when the user click on the button "start", the program need to load the values of `Sheet1` to `main` firstly. After that it checks, if an ID is contained in `Sheet2`. Is for example ID 100 in sheet2 then it compares the `Volume` with the value `Up to`. In Sheet2 you have 3 entries. Well, it checks if 50.000 < 100.000. If it's true, then calculate 50.000 * 0,2 / 100 and return the value to result column of the corresponding ServiceType. In this case => `Service1`. How can I define this in VBA?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Your history suggest you might be able to resolve this for yourself. Also it is not clear how you wanna handle the 3 entries in Sheet2.

Comment: Which exact part of this are you having a problem with?

Comment: @TimWilliams I don't know how to solve it?!

Comment: "It" is not a single operation: if you were doing this manually how would you do it?  Is it one single step, or multiple?  E.g. - How to loop over the input lines from Sheet1 and copy to Main? How to locate the first line on Sheet 2 which has a matching ID (you can use Find() or Match() here)? How to check whether the "Up to" value on that line is greater than "Volume"?  Posting *some* code is 100% more likely to get you answers here than asking for a full solution.

Answer (score 1):

I would concur with CMArg - you question is not well asked and not clear. Presumably you would also have at least attempted something? You should include any attempts here and in which way they fail.

You don't really need VBA, unless it is vitally important for you that the length of your main table automatically adjust to the length of the table in Sheet1. I would just work with tables. VBA tends to be unreliable with newer users (use of fixed ranges, recording of macros, etc). At any rate you can handle that separately - there's still no need for VBA outside of that specific element.

Other remark: the "service" seems to be directly linked to the ID. Therefore you should store it in Sheet1 instead of in sheet 2 & repeating it...

So make 3 tables and name them tMain, tSheet1 and tSheet2 (or adapt following formula to your naming convention), one on each sheet. Though I don't really see the need to put all those on separate sheet given the details you have provided. That would look like this:

[image: tSheet1]

[image: tSheet2]

[image: tMain]

In tMain, you need in your ID column a formula that will return the nth entry of the corresponding row in Sheet1. You could just do

```
tSheet1[@[ID]]
```

However as soon as you tMain & tSheet1 headers aren't on the same row, it won't work. So a safer way to do this is to refer to tMain's header instead as a starting point & then use index() to return the 1, 2, 3... element from tSheet1. LIke so in your ID column in tMain:

```
=INDEX(tSheet1[ID],(ROW()-ROW(tMain[[#Headers],[ID]])))
```

The NAME & Volumn columns of tMain are just an index match:

```
=INDEX(tSheet1[Name],MATCH([@ID],tSheet1[ID],0))
=INDEX(tSheet1[Volume],MATCH([@ID],tSheet1[ID],0))
```

The trickier bit is returning the "service value" (e.g. your service 1, 2, 3 column). Based on your explanations I don't see the need for 3 such columns. At any rate the formula can return the value regardless of which service it is, therefore I would be tempted to do those as 2 seperate steps. So I will add a "service_value" column to your tMain. It will return the MAX value of your percentage column corresponding to your "upto" based on the tMain volume. So with your example, that would mean 50,000*0.2. IF the volume was 110,000 it would multiply by 0.3 etc.

```
{=MAX(IF([@ID]=tSheet2[ID],IF([@Volume]<tSheet2[upto],[@Volume]*tSheet2[percent]),0))}
```

(Note this is an array formula, to be entered with ctlr + alt + enter. Do not enter the {}).

What you have not specified is what to do if the volume is greater than the maximum number specified in tSheet2 for that article/service. We need to know that to properly adapt the formula.

Finally, if you do want the columns for service1, service2 and service3 filled, you can do that in each of them:

```
=IF(INDEX(tSheet1[Service],MATCH([@ID],tSheet1[ID],0))=tMain[[#Headers],[Service1]],[@[service_value]],"")
=IF(INDEX(tSheet1[Service],MATCH([@ID],tSheet1[ID],0))=tMain[[#Headers],[Service2]],[@[service_value]],"")
=IF(INDEX(tSheet1[Service],MATCH([@ID],tSheet1[ID],0))=tMain[[#Headers],[Service3]],[@[service_value]],"")
```

In other words, it checks (in tSheet1 where I have put the specification for the service number as suggested above) if the "service" column in tSheet1 matches the header of the current column (Service1, Service2, Service3...). Of course you need to ensure that the column header matches the name of the service as written in tSheet1. The upside is that if you ever change the service name you only need to edit the column header (as opposed to hard-coding it somewhere).